# Send delete request with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I have a client server application. 
The user should be able to delete an item. So in the url he will just send the ID of the item.

So simply a javascript call like this would be fine.

```
window.location = '/api/games?ItemId'=id ;
```

But of course this would be a GET request and not a delete . So what should I do now.

Just declare it a GET Request on server side or what I do not want to do make it an ajax call.

Comment: with the get request, you can then activate php and run the delete function right? something like this: `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $remove->removeImage($id);
}` and if php code in that file is not possible or wanted, you might have to use ajax to send it to a php handler file

Comment: Browsers are were designed to be just that ... browsers.  i.e they handle GET requests.  Then someone thought it would be handy to able to send some data and along came `<form>` which uses the existing HTTP verb POST.  There's no general way in a *browser* to send a DELETE verb without using javascript.

Comment: If you're using HTML without javascript, then you would POST a `<form>` (to a POST handler) as a work-around.   Then a few years ago someone realised that we should be using the correct verb for the correct action instead of piggy-backing on existing verbs, but there's still no built-in way to send PUT and DELETE requests.

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way than using an ajax request. With jquery it looks like that :

```
$.ajax({
     url : 'myurl',
     method : 'delete',
     data : {
        itemid :id
     }
})
```

Comment: yep my mystake @RoryMcCrossan I did not see the op asked not to use AJAX  and i made a mistake in the data

Comment: There are other ways... fetch

Comment: wich one @epascarello ? I'm genuinely intrigued by that !

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Unfortunately not. The sooner IE fades in to obscurity the better :)

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani Let's just add a polyfill for IE and it will be fine to use `fetch` :)

Comment: when I just used window.location and handled my delete action as a get I could just redirect on the server after the delete was succesful, now that I use ajax with delete method , I will call my delete handler on the server send response back if succesful then I will have to again make a call to the server using window.location to call the page which I want to show. So because I use ajax now I will have 2 server calls.

Comment: so basically my ajax call would get a whole html page as response instead of a json